# React-Axios: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

https://bezkoder.com/react-file-upload-axios/

I am following this fileupload tutorial on React-Axios but hit a very general error that I can't seems to debug. I am very new to react. Any help is appreciated (:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined selectFile
http://localhost:29080/static/js/main.chunk.js:27395:10
  27392 | }
  27393 | 
  27394 | selectFile(event) {
> 27395 |   this.setState({
        |        ^  27396 |     selectedFiles: event.target.files
  27397 |   });
  27398 | }
View source
```

Below is the react component. The code I followed on the tutorial is the exact same. The errors occurs AFTER i click the upload button upon uploading a PNG file

```
export default class FileUpload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedFiles: undefined,
      currentFile: undefined,
      progress: 0,
      message: "",

      fileInfos: [],
    };
  }


  selectFile(event) {
    this.setState({selectedFiles: event.target.files,});
  }

  upload() {
    let currentFile = this.state.selectedFiles[0];

    this.setState({
      progress: 0,
      currentFile: currentFile,
    });

    UploadService.upload(currentFile, (event) => {
      this.setState({
        progress: Math.round((100 * event.loaded) / event.total),
      });
    })
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          message: response.data.message,
        });
        return UploadService.getFiles();
      })
      .then((files) => {
        this.setState({
          fileInfos: files.data,
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({
          progress: 0,
          message: "Could not upload the file!",
          currentFile: undefined,
        });
      });

    this.setState({
      selectedFiles: undefined,
    });
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    UploadService.getFiles().then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        fileInfos: this.response.data,
      });
    });
  }



  render() {
const {
      selectedFiles,
      currentFile,
      progress,
      message,
      fileInfos,
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {currentFile && (
          <div className="progress">
            <div
              className="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped"
              role="progressbar"
              aria-valuenow={progress}
              aria-valuemin="0"
              aria-valuemax="100"
              style={{ width: progress + "%" }}
            >
              {progress}%
            </div>
          </div>
        )}

        <label className="btn btn-default">
          <input type="file" onChange={this.selectFile} />
        </label>

        <button className="btn btn-success"
          disabled={!selectedFiles}
          
          onClick={() => this.currentFile()}
        >
          Upload
        </button>

        <div className="alert alert-light" role="alert">
          {message}
        </div>

        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-header">List of Files</div>
          <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
            {fileInfos &&
              fileInfos.map((file, index) => (
                <li className="list-group-item" key={index}>
                  <a href={file.url}>{file.name}</a>
                </li>
              ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please share a screenshot of your code file

Comment: please show your code?

Comment: You are not using arrow function, please convert the regular function to arrow function it will work.

Comment: is this what u mean? onClick={() => this.currentFile()}

Comment: See [Why we need to bind event handlers in Class Components in React](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `this.selectFile = this.selectFile.bind(this)` in `constructor`, after you declare `this.state`

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** Your state update function `selectFile` thinks that `this` is referring to itself.

**Fix:** The previous answer of force binding by @viet should work.

**Another Solution:** Making the onChange property as a closure instead of *passing function handle* should fix `this`.

```js
onChange={(event) => this.selectFile(event)}
```

---

**IMP: Why?:** This works because you can think of `(event) => this.selectFile(event)` to be evaluated in the render-context - i.e. as if it's executing inside your render fn at the spot its defined. In that case `this` refers to the Component object.

Good luck with reactJS!